# What's the official status of the DPR (and LPR) militias under the laws of the Russian Federation?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, military, donbass

Interestingly, TASS still posts news about the feats of the DPR militia, e.g. there's one dated [Jan 10](https://tass.com/politics/1560039), and it seems to be from 2023 (as it references M777 howitzers, which Ukraine didn't have last year).

So, what's the official status of these forces (DPR militia) under the laws of the Russian Federation? Were they incorporated in the Russian armed forces, and on what level/basis?

Comment: "as it references M777 howitzers, which Ukraine didn't have last year" That howitzers were delivered to Ukraine by the West already last sumer or even earlier.

Comment: @convert:  I mean last year in January they didn't have those.

Comment: They are suggested to be incorporated into Russian armed forces, but that did not happen yet; reasons include them seemingly having better war prowess than AF of RF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least for LPR they now becoming part of Armed Forces of Russia, as can be read in [this Russian article](https://vesiskitim.ru/2022/12/22/narodnaia-militsiia-lnr-s-1-ianvaria-2023-goda-mozhet-stat-chastiu-vooruzhennykh-sil-rossii-news?ysclid=lcxqp0eyrd931318304):

> **The People's Militia of the LPR may become part of the Armed Forces of Russia from January 1, 2023**
>
> This was announced by the acting head of the LPR Leonid Pasechnik.
>
> The People's Militia of the LPR may become part of the Russian Armed
> Forces from January 1, 2023.
>
> "Today we are together, we are part of the Russian Federation. I
> understand that from January 1, the People's Militia units will become
> part of the Armed Forces of the Russian Federation," said Pasechnik.
>
> On September 30, Putin signed agreements according to which the DPR,
> LPR, Zaporozhye and Kherson regions will become part of Russia. The
> project of the territories becoming part of the Russian Federation
> implied that in all four subjects the transition period would last
> until January 1. After January 1, all structures, such as the People's
> Militia of the LPR, will become part of the structures of the Russian
> Federation.

Comment: It is somewhat vague, but I guess it's as good as it gets.

Comment: @Fizz It might help to get a better understanding of how the military in Russia actually functions too. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwuRpYw7vyw Task & Purpose does a good job of highlighting some of those elements in this video. Even if they are incorporated into the official military it does not necessarily mean they are very different.